# Android - how to replace part of a string by another string?

Tags: java, android, string

I have strings with some numbers and english words and I need to translate them to my mother tongue by finding them and replacing them by locallized version of this word. Do you know how to easily achieve replacing words in a string?

Thanks

Edit:

I have tried (part of a string "to" should be replaced by "xyz"):

```
string.replace("to", "xyz")
```

But it is not working...

Answer (score 200, accepted):

It is working, but it wont modify the caller object, but returning a new String.
 
So you just need to assign it to a new String variable, or to itself:

```
string = string.replace("to", "xyz");
```

or

```
String newString = string.replace("to", "xyz");
```

**API Docs**

```
public String replace (CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

**Since: API Level 1**

> Copies this string replacing
>   occurrences of the specified target
>   sequence with another sequence. The
>   string is processed from the beginning
>   to the end.

**Parameters**

- `target`  the sequence to replace.
- `replacement`  the replacement
  sequence.

**Returns** the resulting string. 
**Throws** `NullPointerException`  if target or replacement is null.

Comment: How can I mreplace multipel things? For example, `Replace letter h or l`?

Answer (score 2):

MAY BE INTERESTING TO YOU:

In java, string objects are immutable. Immutable simply means unmodifiable or unchangeable.

Once string object is created its data or state can't be changed but a new string object is created.

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin there is no replaceAll, so I created this loop to replace repeated values ​​in a string or any variable.

```
 var someValue = "https://www.google.com.br/"
    while (someValue.contains(".")) {
        someValue = someValue.replace(".", "")
    }
Log.d("newValue :", someValue)
// in that case the stitches have been removed
//https://wwwgooglecombr/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "to";
str.replace("to", "xyz");
```

Just try it :)

Answer (score -2):

rekaszeru

I noticed that you commented in 2011 but i thought i should post this answer anyway, in case anyone needs to "replace the original string" and runs into this answer ..

**Im using a EditText as an example**

---

// GIVE TARGET TEXT BOX A NAME

```
 EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_textboxID);
```

// STRING TO REPLACE

```
 String oldText = "hello"
 String newText = "Hi";      
 String textBoxText = textbox.getText().toString();
```

// REPLACE STRINGS WITH RETURNED STRINGS

```
String returnedString = textBoxText.replace( oldText, newText );
```

// USE RETURNED STRINGS TO REPLACE NEW STRING INSIDE TEXTBOX

```
textbox.setText(returnedString);
```

This is untested, but it's just an example of using the returned string to replace the original layouts string with setText()  !

Obviously this example requires that you have a EditText with the ID set to your_textboxID

Answer (score -3):

You're doing only one mistake.

use `replaceAll()` function over there.

e.g.

```
String str = "Hi";
String str1 = "hello";
str.replaceAll( str, str1 );
```

Comment: -- Neither the `replaceAll() ` function changes the original string, it returns the processed string as a result!