# Android Replace Strings

Tags: android

How do you replace strings when you retrieve a data from an activity ? I cant seems to find it google. Maybe my question is too simple. Please see the below codes.

```
Intent in = getIntent();
textToPass = in.getStringExtra("textToPass");
```

textToPass is actually a string eg. "ExampleText.txt"

How do you remove the .txt to make it look like "ExampleText"

I might be somewhere near, but I still couldnt figure out

```
String exampletext = textToPass.getText().toString().replace(".txt","");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754363/android-how-to-replace-part-of-a-string-by-another-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here textToPass is string so you can directly apply replace method on it .

```
textToPass.replace(".txt","");
```

Comment: thanks. Got it now. Will accept your answer after the lock releases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String textToPass = in.getStringExtra("textToPass");
String[] exampletext = textToPass.split("//.");
```

Then use exampletext[0] it must give your expectation result