# Date in android document title?

Tags: android, eclipse, date, pdf

Well, Im having a PDF generated in and android application, but I need the title to have the date and time of the system. So I compiled this code:

```
public void createPDF()
{
    Document doc = new Document();

     try {
         Date date = new Date();
         String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
         File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Bitacora");
         dir.mkdirs();
         File file = new File(dir, "Bitácora "+idetotrocliente.getText().toString()+", "+dateTime+vwfecha1.getText().toString()+etsitio.getText().toString()+".pdf");
         FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

But when I try to generate the PDF in the app, the log gives me this error:

```
08-28 21:32:38.950: E/PDFCreator(12425): ioException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Bitacora/Bitácora ¡VALOR NECESARIO!, ago 28, 2013 9:32:24 p.m..pdf (Invalid argument)
```

And when I delete the "dateTime" variable, the PDF generates correctly, but I need the date to be in the title. What can I do? :(

Comment: Errors seems to be of FileNotFound. Are you sure that the file name contains the date and time in its name... and in same format and order ? Ty to print the name that you are rying to use and hen cpmpae with the actual name of tile.

Comment: may be the dateTime variable has a special char not allowed to name a file like /

Comment: IT may be how the sistem gives me the date. Is there any other way to get a date without forbidden characters?

Comment: The format now is "Mm dd, yyyy hr:min:sec am"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be because of `:`. See [What characters allowed in file names on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android) . `:` is sort of reserved char, so can't be used in filename. Try to replace that with `""`( i.e empty string) using [.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) function. Then use it to create PDF. Also see [Android - how to replace part of a string by another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754363/android-how-to-replace-part-of-a-string-by-another-string)