# String replace android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, pdf

Im trying to replace a character : on a system date generated so I can put it as a title. It gives me the format:  "ago 29, 2013 7:42:19 p.m.", so I need to change the ":" for " ", with an string replace.  But I dont know how to do it. Ill appreciate your help. Heres my code:

```
    public void createPDF()
    {
        Document doc = new Document();


         try {
             Date date = new Date();
            String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
             File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Bitacora");
             dir.mkdirs();
             File file = new File(dir, "Bitácora "+idetotrocliente.getText().toString()+", "+dateTime+etsitio.getText().toString()+".pdf");
             FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                 }
             catch(Exception)
             {

             }
    }
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754363/android-how-to-replace-part-of-a-string-by-another-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [String.replace(old, new)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

```
String dateTime = "ago 29, 2013 7:42:19 p.m.";
dateTime = dateTime.replace(":", " ");
System.out.println("dateTime : "+dateTime);
```

output : `dateTime : ago 29, 2013 7 42 19 p.m.`

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want:

```
 String orig = "ago 29, 2013 7:42:19 p.m.";
String updated = orig.replace(":", " ");
System.out.println(updated);
```