# Using Jsoup is it possible to remove text characters after white space?

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup, whitespace, element

Using Jsoup is it possible to remove text characters after whitespace?

For example:

```
 <td>  4.9 ft</td>
```

Is it possible to remove the "ft" from the result?

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible, yet I don't what jsoup would have to do with this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsoup will not help you with that. However, you can parse the Element(s) into a String, and then replace part of the string with another. An example is below:

```
String parsedstring = YourElement.text();
String replacedstring = parsedstring.replace(" ft","");
```

Here's another question that may help you: [Android - how to replace part of a string by another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754363/android-how-to-replace-part-of-a-string-by-another-string)

Comment: Lovely, Thanks I modded it slightly...String parsedstring = yourElement.text().replace(" ft", "");   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Save the text as String.
2) Get the length of the String, then use the substring method to remove the last two characters.

Here's an example

```
String result = Element.text();
int resultLength = result.length();
result = result.substring(0, resultLength -2);
```

Please note: This is a beginner's advice.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing your help. I have accepted a different answer but still, thanks for your in-put. Appreciated.