# Custom Functionality: Add Specific Symbol While Typing Into Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am trying to add a functionality to an existing app, 
The Functionality is to add a specific symbol with a space, while the user is typing. i have already tried this with `afterTextChaanged();` What i want to do is
Supporse the user types : i am fine thank you, then it should be automatically converted to : @i @am @fine @thankyou. can you please help me with this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    edittext.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    String oldstr=edittext.getText().toString();
    String newstr=oldstr.replaceAll("\\s+","@");
    edittext.setText(newstr);
    edittext.removeTextChangedListener(this);
      }
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)  {

       }

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){


     }
});
```

Comment: No Lucks, it makes a recursive call

Comment: what  recursive call?

Comment: check my Edited answer

Comment: the issue is , it is working as normal edittext even after implementing your code

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754363/android-how-to-replace-part-of-a-string-by-another-string).

You should be able to replace all the spaces with something like `' @'`.

Just call

```
string = string.replace(" ", " @");
```

in your listener.

Of course, you should also take care of the first word, which (typically) should not have any space before.
You could use a placeholder to do so, like

```
<string name="converted_string">@%1$s</string>
```

then in java

```
your_textView.setText(getString(R.string.converted_string, yourNewReplaceString));
```

Comment: No Lucks, it makes a recursive call