# Create TextView or EditText editable with template

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I got this situation that i have to find `*` and replace with editable text for example: "HI *, What your order * some text. some more text * after". Now i need output like this `Hi ____, What your order ____ some text. some more text ___ after` how can i achieve this in Android please help thanks.

Comment: You want '_' in place of  '*' ?

Comment: Add an example of input String and output String . Cause i don't get what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: you can find many of solution to do that u want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754363/android-how-to-replace-part-of-a-string-by-another-string

Comment: @Ankita  Those dashed i want to input text from user, i'll get template with stars in it and i need to replace with editable text

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Spit the strings by using this post :-

[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

And then add edittext after each string to show output like yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is Easy dude!

Just store your template in Preference, then take values from user and show it back to user with template.

For example; i Stored following in Preference:
I used specific keywords here to differentiate user's response:

> Hi (name), What your order (order) some text. some more text (other)
>   after

where (name) is for user's name;

(order) is for user's order; and

(other) is for other info.

Now, take input from User by some Input field form, and use preference like this.

> String mTemplate = "Hi (name), What your order (order) some text. some
>   more text (other) after";

Replace keywords with user's response like this;

> mTemplate.replace("(name)","UserName_goes_here").replace("(order)","UserOrder_goes_here").replace("(other)","OtherInfo_goes_here");

Here, you'll get strings with your template. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I need to show full text with `EditText` in between, i want user to type data in `EditText` fields. Your method is good for constant template but i have dynamic template coming from internet and need to show like that